# How to reference an email when iterating emails in a folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

When Outlook starts, I need my VBA to run on a folder in a secondary email account to see if anyone moved emails with attachments there during the time my computer was shut down. I want to save the attachments.

I have other code that monitors the folder while Outlook is running and saves the attachments. It also adds a note to the email "The file(s) were saved to C:\Temp\TEST".

When Outlook starts, I want to scan the emails in the folder for ones that do not have the text "The file(s) were saved to C:\Temp\TEST" and then save those attachments.

I know the save/add text portion of the script works, however, I get

> "Object Variable or With Block not set"

on this line:

```
If InStr(1, LCase(ItemCrnt.Body), LCase("The file(s) were saved to")) > 0 Then
```

I suspect it must be the way I'm defining variables.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olAccount As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim ItemCrnt As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olAccount = ns.CreateRecipient("xyz@mycompany.com")

olAccount.Resolve

Set olInbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(WLAccount, olFolderInbox)
Set ItemCrnt = olInbox.Folders("My Folder").Items

' First check the folders and make sure that any exisiting emails in the 
folders have already had attachments saved to the strFolderpath

' Get the path to the folder
strFolderpath = "C:\Temp\TEST\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and add a note to the message with 
the file path.

With ItemCrnt

    ' This code only saves attachments from mail items.
    'If .Class = olMail Then
        'Check if the attachments have already been saved
        If InStr(1, LCase(ItemCrnt.Body), LCase("The file(s) were saved to")) > 0 Then
            ' ...code to save attachments and add text to body of message goes here...
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i believe on Outlook startup, your inbox is not really "ready" yet, so ItemCrnt is basically `Nothing`, hence error object variable block not set.  May be try the `.OnTime` to delay the procedure. Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It's look like the folder is empty. you can add condition to first check if the Object `ItemCrnt` is empty. Please note that the Object `ItemCrnt` is an array of all the items in your folder and there for you can't use `.Body` on it, you first need to reference to some object in the array e.g `ItemCrnt(1).Body`

Comment: WLAccount was not defined-- do you mean olAccount ?? or should WLAccount, be removed ??  Two EndIf without enuf IF-s -- take one out?  Also, you need to check ItemCrnt.Items.Count to determine if there are any items.

Comment: You have set ItemCrnt to `olInbox.Folders("My Folder").Items` which is a collection of the items in “My Folder”.  Defined like this, ItemCrnt does not have a Body.  You need something like: `For Each ItemCrnt in olInbox.Folders("My Folder").Items ` ... `Next`.  If that is not clear, I can expand.

Comment: @TonyDallimore thank you for pointing that out! This resolved my issue. I also had to move the For Each prior to the With block to do the search for the string and then save attachments.

Comment: I am pleased my hint gave the start you needed.  I knew it wasn’t the complete solution hence my offer to expand.  However, for my own development, I find solving my own problems after being given a hint far more helpful than being given a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim ns As namespace
    Dim myAccount As Recipient
    Dim myInbox As folder
    
    Dim fldrItems As Items
    Dim ItemCrnt As Object
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myAccount = ns.CreateRecipient("xyz@mycompany.com")
    
    ' Names can be resolved, anything in address format is "accepted" as resolved.
    ' myAccount.Resolve
    
    ' WLAccount     ' <-- Option Explicit
    'Set olInbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(WLAccount, olFolderInbox)
    
    Set myInbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myAccount, olFolderInbox)
    
    Set fldrItems = myInbox.folders("My Folder").Items
    
    ' Check each item.
    For i = 1 To fldrItems.Count
    
        ' process mail items only.
        If fldrItems(i).Class = olMail Then
        
            Set ItemCrnt = fldrItems(i)
    
            With ItemCrnt
                Debug.Print ItemCrnt.subject
            End With
            
        End If
        
    Next

End Sub
```